# React: Fetching inside a map and modifying a useState array

Tags: reactjs, json, react-hooks, fetch

Can you guys please help me with a basic React app :)
I want to read a json file:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "Google",
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "status": "to evaluate"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bing",
        "url": "www.bing.com",
        "status": "to evaluate"
    },
    etc.
]
```

While reading it, I want to fetch the url to fill the status in this json file

finally, I just want to make a table that has two columns: the first is the name with the url, the second is the status

I tried this but it does not work :O

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table'
import jsonData from './data/urls.json'

function ListUrls () {
    const [jsonArray, setJsonArray] = useState(jsonData)

    async function fetchData (array) {
        try {
            array.map (url => {
                const response = await fetch(url.url)
                setJsonArray(url.status = response.status)
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error', error);
        }
        
    fetchData(jsonArray)

    return (
        <div>
            <Table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {jsonArray.map(url => (
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href={url.url} target='_blank'}>
                                    {url.name}
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {url.status}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ListUrls
```

Btw, I would really want to use hooks to do it :)

So, I would except to see this table, but the page is blank :/

[image]

Comment: Hey! The page it's just blank. I expect to see a table filled with the fetch status response from the urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by the others,  you will need to use `useEffect` in this case. Otherwise your `fetchData` will be called over and over every time you update the state. I would also change the way you call those URLs to get their http status to using promises (just cuz I like promises). Here is how I would write your code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import jsonData from "./urls.json";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(jsonData);

  useEffect(() => {
    const promises = jsonData.map((url, i) => {
      return fetch(url.url).then((r) => ({ fetch: r, index: i }));
    });

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then((result) => {
        const new_data = result.map((d) => {
          jsonData[d.index].status = d.fetch.status;
          return jsonData[d.index];
        });
        setData(new_data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("Handle error here");
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((url, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
              <td>
                <a href={url.url} target={"_blank"}>
                  {url.name}
                </a>
              </td>
              <td>{url.status}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note that I am using the regular `<table>` instead of your prebuilt element `<Table>` as I don't have it. Here is a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-jang-yrxv3?file=/src/App.js:285-286

---

`fetch` returns a promise, which, when resolved, yields the fetch response object. So if you only have one fetch to do you can call it like so:

```
fetch(url).then(response => {//do stuff here with response object})
```

But let's say you have multiple `fetch` commands as you do in your case. How do you resolve them with just one `then`. Well that's where `Promise.all()` comes in handy. The idea is to get all the promises from your `fetch` commands and then resolve them all in one shot. As such:

```
const promises = jsonData.map((url, i) => {
      return fetch(url.url).then((r) => ({ fetch: r, index: i }));
    });
```

`promises` will be an array of promises that all the `fetch` commands inside the `map` return. One caveat here is I also return the index of the specific URL so that later you can use it to see which URL corresponds to which HTTP code. And finally you resolve them all using:

```
    Promise.all(promises)
      .then((result) => {
            ...
            ...
```

Simple right?

Comment: Hey! It works!!! Thanks :D I was wondering if you can give me a little bit of explanations because I'm not sure to understand. What does exactly Promise.all() ?

Comment: @user13425812 I have added some details to help you understand the concept.

Comment: hey! I just saw that I have a CORS problem with the fetches, can you help me with this :O Firefox says: Cross-Origin Request Bloques: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at _. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). Status code: 404. --- And Chrome/Edge say: Access to fetch at '_' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been bloques by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

You should change jsonArray to jsonData as the parameter and set the initial state to be null.

Currently you are passing in the state (jsonArray) instead of jsonData when calling the function.
Also you should put the call to fetchData in a useEffect with jsonData as the parameter:

```
useEffect(() => fetchData(jsonData), [jsonData, fetchData]);
```

Comment: But my question is, how do I loop through all the urls if i put the fetch in useEffect() ?

Answer (score 0):

Would this become a loop? Component loads -> `fetchData()` is called -> `fetchData()` updates the state -> Component reloads -> repeat.

You could use a `useEffect()` hook with an empty array as the second argument to only run once:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  //Update json as you were doing;
}, []);
```

Comment: But my question is, how do I loop through all the urls if i put the fetch in useEffect() ?